# Why my code works with arrow function and broken with bind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, orbit.js

I have thought that `bind(this)` is an equivalent of the arrow function however I have met an issue(

This is a store which purpose to track delayed requests. I am using the orbitjs library to save everything into IndexedDB. It provides api which allows to subscribe to db changes, so here my store:

```
export class DelayedRequestsStore implements IDelayedRequests {
    add = addHttpRequest;
    list = queryHttpRequests;
    remove = removeHttpRequest;

    @observable private _delayedRequestsCount = 0;

    @computed get any(): boolean {
        return this._delayedRequestsCount > 0;
    }

    @computed get empty(): boolean {
        return !this.any;
    }

    constructor(db: Sources) {
        db.source.on('update', () => {
            this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
        });
        this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
    }

    private async _updateDelayedRequestsCount(): Promise<void> {
        const delayedRequests = await this.list();
        runInAction(() => {
            this._delayedRequestsCount = delayedRequests.length;
        });
    }
}
```

See that code on constructor

```
    constructor(db: Sources) {
        db.source.on('update', () => {
            this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
        });
        this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
    }
```

And some code on react:

```
<button onClick={async () => {
    await notifyServer(); 
    await clearRequestsFromIndexedDb();
    goToAnotherPage();
})>Cancel</button>
```

Everything works well until I have not changed the constructor code to

```
    constructor(db: Sources) {
        db.source.on('update', this._updateDelayedRequestsCount.bind(this));
        this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
    }
```

With that change I have not seeing any errors in console but `Cancel` button is not working. I have debugged and found that `notifyServer` has been called, then `clearRequestsFromIndexedDb` has been called but `goToAnotherPage` not called, like if error occured in `clearRequestsFromIndexedDb`, but no errors. SO I rollbacked back to arrow function everything works again. Does it can affect anything? Or the problem actually in some other place I am missing?

Comment: I think there might be issue with "this", but not sure, unless we get some working code

Answer (score -1):

I see that you bound `this` only to `db.source.on('update', ... )`. But the call for `this._updateDelayedRequestsCount()` in your constructor has no binding. This could be a problem.

You can explicitly bind `this` to every call of you method like this:

```js
constructor(db: Sources) {
    this._updateDelayedRequestsCount = this._updateDelayedRequestsCount.bind(this);
    
    db.source.on('update', this._updateDelayedRequestsCount);
        
    this._updateDelayedRequestsCount();
    }
```

Maybe it will fix your problem.

Comment: Calling a method as `this.foo()` works fine without explicitly binding anything.

Comment: @deceze You are right. I got it wrong. Thanks and sorry.